# Find the average value of a column based on date column and more than one other columns

Tags: r

I have the dataframe below and I want to calculate for every `PLAYER_NAME` the average `FGM` per 5 `MINS` for the last 2 `game_date`.

```
df<-structure(list(game_date = structure(c(19153, 19153, 19153, 19153, 
19153, 19153, 19153, 19153, 19153, 19153, 19153, 19153, 19153, 
19153, 19153, 19153, 19153, 19156, 19156, 19156, 19156, 19156, 
19156, 19156, 19156, 19156, 19156, 19156, 19156, 19156, 19156, 
19156, 19156, 19156, 19156, 19156, 19156, 19156, 19156, 19156, 
19156, 19156, 19156, 19156, 19159, 19159, 19159, 19159, 19159, 
19159, 19159, 19159, 19159, 19159, 19159, 19159, 19159, 19159, 
19159, 19159, 19159, 19159, 19159, 19159, 19159, 19159), class = "Date"), 
    MIN = c(28.083, 40.683, 9, 40.823, 32.96, 14.5, 39.95, 43.427, 
    28.16, 39.7, 9.9, 42.667, 35.55, 31.45, 20.547, 12.533, 10.067, 
    3.933, 32.847, 37.13, 4.72, 39.625, 34.983, 14.617, 1.317, 
    39.703, 42.533, 16.75, 44.05, 26.155, 1.317, 44.417, 21.413, 
    1.317, 30.237, 1.317, 14.287, 16.067, 1.317, 1.317, 4.683, 
    1.317, 1.317, 1.317, 1.017, 39.215, 39.918, 41.302, 41.817, 
    13.05, 1.05, 38.483, 43.682, 21.667, 44, 19.767, 40.21, 16.452, 
    1.05, 32.623, 17.782, 15.85, 1.017, 1.05, 7.95, 1.05), FGM = c(2, 
    14, 0, 7, 1, 0, 7, 7, 3, 9, 2, 8, 4, 3, 6, 1, 0, 0, 3, 7, 
    0, 7, 3, 1, 0, 7, 12, 1, 5, 6, 0, 10, 0, 1, 4, 0, 4, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 12, 5, 5, 2, 0, 4, 7, 0, 12, 2, 6, 1, 
    0, 4, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), PLAYER_NAME = c("Al Horford", "Stephen Curry", 
    "Nemanja Bjelica", "Klay Thompson", "Draymond Green", "Otto Porter Jr.", 
    "Marcus Smart", "Andrew Wiggins", "Kevon Looney", "Jaylen Brown", 
    "Gary Payton II", "Jayson Tatum", "Derrick White", "Robert Williams III", 
    "Jordan Poole", "Grant Williams", "Payton Pritchard", "Andre Iguodala", 
    "Al Horford", "Stephen Curry", "Nemanja Bjelica", "Klay Thompson", 
    "Draymond Green", "Otto Porter Jr.", "Nik Stauskas", "Marcus Smart", 
    "Andrew Wiggins", "Kevon Looney", "Jaylen Brown", "Gary Payton II", 
    "Damion Lee", "Jayson Tatum", "Derrick White", "Luke Kornet", 
    "Robert Williams III", "Juan Toscano-Anderson", "Jordan Poole", 
    "Grant Williams", "Juwan Morgan", "Aaron Nesmith", "Payton Pritchard", 
    "Jonathan Kuminga", "Moses Moody", "Sam Hauser", "Andre Iguodala", 
    "Al Horford", "Stephen Curry", "Klay Thompson", "Draymond Green", 
    "Otto Porter Jr.", "Nik Stauskas", "Marcus Smart", "Andrew Wiggins", 
    "Kevon Looney", "Jaylen Brown", "Gary Payton II", "Jayson Tatum", 
    "Derrick White", "Luke Kornet", "Robert Williams III", "Jordan Poole", 
    "Grant Williams", "Juwan Morgan", "Aaron Nesmith", "Payton Pritchard", 
    "Sam Hauser")), row.names = c(NA, -66L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the average `FGM` for the two most recent games normalized to 5 minutes using `dplyr`'s `arrange`, `slice`, and `summarize`

```
df %>% 
  arrange(game_date) %>%
  slice(tail(row_number(), 2), .by = PLAYER_NAME) %>%
  summarize(avg_fgm = mean(FGM/MIN*5), .by = PLAYER_NAME)
```

Output:

```
   PLAYER_NAME   avg_fgm
   <chr>           <dbl>
 1 Al Horford      0.611
 2 Stephen Curry   1.22 
 3 Nemanja Bjelica 0    
 4 Klay Thompson   0.744
 5 Draymond Green  0.513
 6 Otto Porter Jr. 0.554
 7 Marcus Smart    0.701
 8 Andrew Wiggins  1.11 
 9 Kevon Looney    0.149
10 Jaylen Brown    0.966
# ℹ 17 more rows
```

Comment: thanks how can you be sure in the code that the 2 recognizes the last 2 game dates?

Comment: No problem! The `arrange(game_date)` organizes the data by descending date of game, so the most recent games are last. then the `slice(tail(...), 2)` takes the last two rows (games).

Comment: based on your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76272556/run-a-calculation-for-a-range-of-consecutive-columns-in-dataframe

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `dplyr` package and `summarise` function to calculate something per group `group_by`.
If you need only last two days, you can previously run `filter` where you indicate the preferred time range.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(time_slot_5_min = cut(MIN, seq(0, 60, 5))) %>%
  dplyr::group_by( PLAYER_NAME, time_slot_5_min) %>%
  summarise( FGM = mean(FGM))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>%
  group_by(PLAYER_NAME) %>%
  arrange(desc(game_date)) %>%
  filter(row_number() <= 2) %>%
  summarise(avg_FGM_5MINS = mean(FGM / (MIN / 5)))
```

Output

```
PLAYER_NAME    avg_FGM_5MINS
   <chr>                  <dbl>
 1 Aaron Nesmith          0    
 2 Al Horford             0.611
 3 Andre Iguodala         0    
 4 Andrew Wiggins         1.11 
 5 Damion Lee             0    
 6 Derrick White          0.152
 7 Draymond Green         0.513
 8 Gary Payton II         0.826
 9 Grant Williams         0.313
10 Jaylen Brown           0.966
# ℹ 17 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Comment: This is returns incorrect information