# Run a calculation for a range of consecutive columns in dataframe

Tags: r

In the dataframe below I find the average FGM for the two most recent games normalized to 5 minutes using

```
df %>% 
  arrange(game_date) %>%
  slice(tail(row_number(), 2), .by = PLAYER_NAME) %>%
  summarize(FGM = mean(FGM/MIN*5), .by = PLAYER_NAME)
```

What if I want to apply the same to a range of columns in my dataframe rather than only. Here for example I want to automate the process to find the same for `FGA`. My columns are more in my real dataset but I think if I could run a loop to range for example `4:5` that would work. The column name should remain the same as the initial.

```
df<-structure(list(game_date = structure(c(19153, 19153, 19156, 19156, 
19156, 19156, 19156, 19156, 19156, 19156, 19156, 19156, 19156, 
19156, 19156, 19156, 19156, 19156, 19156, 19156, 19156, 19156, 
19156, 19156, 19156, 19156, 19156, 19156, 19156, 19159, 19159, 
19159, 19159, 19159, 19159, 19159, 19159, 19159, 19159, 19159, 
19159, 19159, 19159, 19159, 19159, 19159, 19159, 19159, 19159, 
19159, 19159), class = "Date"), MIN = c(12.533, 10.067, 3.933, 
32.847, 37.13, 4.72, 39.625, 34.983, 14.617, 1.317, 39.703, 42.533, 
16.75, 44.05, 26.155, 1.317, 44.417, 21.413, 1.317, 30.237, 1.317, 
14.287, 16.067, 1.317, 1.317, 4.683, 1.317, 1.317, 1.317, 1.017, 
39.215, 39.918, 41.302, 41.817, 13.05, 1.05, 38.483, 43.682, 
21.667, 44, 19.767, 40.21, 16.452, 1.05, 32.623, 17.782, 15.85, 
1.017, 1.05, 7.95, 1.05), FGM = c(1, 0, 0, 3, 7, 0, 7, 3, 1, 
0, 7, 12, 1, 5, 6, 0, 10, 0, 1, 4, 0, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 6, 12, 5, 5, 2, 0, 4, 7, 0, 12, 2, 6, 1, 0, 4, 5, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0), FGA = c(2, 2, 0, 6, 22, 0, 14, 6, 3, 0, 15, 23, 2, 18, 
8, 1, 20, 4, 1, 5, 0, 8, 2, 0, 1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 8, 21, 20, 10, 
3, 1, 12, 18, 2, 23, 6, 18, 6, 0, 8, 12, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0), PLAYER_NAME = c("Grant Williams", 
"Payton Pritchard", "Andre Iguodala", "Al Horford", "Stephen Curry", 
"Nemanja Bjelica", "Klay Thompson", "Draymond Green", "Otto Porter Jr.", 
"Nik Stauskas", "Marcus Smart", "Andrew Wiggins", "Kevon Looney", 
"Jaylen Brown", "Gary Payton II", "Damion Lee", "Jayson Tatum", 
"Derrick White", "Luke Kornet", "Robert Williams III", "Juan Toscano-Anderson", 
"Jordan Poole", "Grant Williams", "Juwan Morgan", "Aaron Nesmith", 
"Payton Pritchard", "Jonathan Kuminga", "Moses Moody", "Sam Hauser", 
"Andre Iguodala", "Al Horford", "Stephen Curry", "Klay Thompson", 
"Draymond Green", "Otto Porter Jr.", "Nik Stauskas", "Marcus Smart", 
"Andrew Wiggins", "Kevon Looney", "Jaylen Brown", "Gary Payton II", 
"Jayson Tatum", "Derrick White", "Luke Kornet", "Robert Williams III", 
"Jordan Poole", "Grant Williams", "Juwan Morgan", "Aaron Nesmith", 
"Payton Pritchard", "Sam Hauser")), row.names = c(NA, -51L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option could be:

```
df %>%
 arrange(game_date) %>%
 group_by(PLAYER_NAME) %>%
 summarise(across(c(FGM, FGA), ~ mean((./MIN * 5)[row_number() >= (n() - 1)])))

   PLAYER_NAME      FGM   FGA
   <chr>          <dbl> <dbl>
 1 Aaron Nesmith  0     1.90 
 2 Al Horford     0.611 0.967
 3 Andre Iguodala 0     0    
 4 Andrew Wiggins 1.11  2.38 
 5 Damion Lee     0     3.80 
 6 Derrick White  0.152 1.38 
 7 Draymond Green 0.513 1.03 
 8 Gary Payton II 0.826 1.52 
 9 Grant Williams 0.313 0.627
10 Jaylen Brown   0.966 2.33
```

Comment: how can you be sure that this happens slice(tail(row_number(), 2) meaning that I need only the last more recent game_date?

Comment: Because the part `[row_number() >= (n() - 1)]` subsets the last two rows :)

Comment: if  i want it for the last 5 game_date? [row_number() >= (n() - 4)]?

Comment: That's it exactly :)

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try the below code

```r
df %>% arrange(game_date) %>% group_by(PLAYER_NAME) %>% 
  slice(tail(row_number(), 2)) %>%
  mutate(across(c(FGM,FGA), ~ mean(.x/MIN*5))) %>% slice_tail(n=1)
```

```
# A tibble: 49 × 5
# Groups:   PLAYER_NAME [27]
   game_date    MIN   FGM   FGA PLAYER_NAME   
   <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>         
 1 2022-06-13  1.32 0     1.90  Aaron Nesmith 
 2 2022-06-16  1.05 0     1.90  Aaron Nesmith 
 3 2022-06-13 32.8  0.611 0.967 Al Horford    
 4 2022-06-16 39.2  0.611 0.967 Al Horford    
 5 2022-06-13  3.93 0     0     Andre Iguodala
 6 2022-06-16  1.02 0     0     Andre Iguodala
 7 2022-06-13 42.5  1.11  2.38  Andrew Wiggins
 8 2022-06-16 43.7  1.11  2.38  Andrew Wiggins
 9 2022-06-13  1.32 0     3.80  Damion Lee    
10 2022-06-13 21.4  0.152 1.38  Derrick White 
# … with 39 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Comment: what n=1 is for?

Comment: here n=1 is the number of rows to be selected per group